# Aplicar en un JPanel el eliminado de un JButton desde una BD SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, interfaz-gráfica

Muy Buenas, Resulta que mi programa al iniciar recrea los JButtons basandose en una BD con un WHILE, y ya tengo programada la parte en la que puedo eliminar la persona desde un JTable, Lo que pasa es que al hacerlo el JPanel sigue mostrando el JButton que ya supuestamente fue eliminado, Algun consejo?

Metodo con el que cargo los JButtons

```
public void cargarBotonesInstaladores(){
    try{
        Connection miConexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:instaladores3Claro.db");
    Statement miStatement = miConexion.createStatement();
    ResultSet miResultSet = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT id, name, identification, color FROM instaladores3Claro");

    while(miResultSet.next()){

            Person p = new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"),
            miResultSet.getString("identification"));

            PersonAction pa = new PersonAction(p);

            JButton jb = new JButton(pa);

            jb.setBackground(getColor(miResultSet.getString("color")));
            pnlIns.add(jb);
            pnlIns.revalidate();
            pnlIns.repaint();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Boton que efectua el metodo de eliminar:

```
private void eliminarInsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    int filasel;
    String id;
    try 
    {
        filasel = tblInstaladores.getSelectedRow();
        if(filasel == -1)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha seleccionado ninguna fila a eliminar");
        }
        else
        {
        modeloIns = (DefaultTableModel) tblInstaladores.getModel();    
        id = (String) modeloIns.getValueAt(filasel, 0);
        EliminarIns(id);
        }
        pnlIns.revalidate();
        pnlIns.repaint();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Metodo que elimina:

```
void EliminarIns(String id){

    try{
        Connection miConexionInstaladores = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:instaladores3Claro.db");
        PreparedStatement pst = miConexionInstaladores.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM instaladores3Claro "+
                "WHERE id = "+id);
        Statement miStatementIns = miConexionInstaladores.createStatement();

        int m = pst.executeUpdate();
        if(m > 0){
            CargarTablaInstaladores("");
        }



    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Ojala me puedan ayudar :)

[image: Lugar en donde agrego los JButtons]

[image: Lugar en donde administro los JButtons, (Eliminar, Editar)]

Comment: remueve el jbutton del panel y haz el repaint, pon el código desde donde lo estás eliminando.

Comment: Lo removeria si supiera como referirme a ese boton, Ya que al crearse con la BD la VariableName no la puedo saber :c, Y ok ya añado el metodo

Comment: Listo @Sr1871 ya

Comment: El registro se elimina cuando presionas ese botón que quieres quitar?

Comment: Si, Osea, De la BD se elimina totalmente, Lo que pasa es que el JButton aun asi se queda, Pero la funcion que tenia, La perdio, Osea que si se elimina el registro

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero me imagino que eliminarInsActionPerfomed se lo pasas a un listener de un JButton, se lo pasas al mismo botón que deseas eliminar o se invoca desde otro botón este action, podrías poner una imagen para entender como está tu estructura?

Comment: El boton que deseo eliminar no es el que efectua la accion de eliminar, De hecho el boton que elimina es un PopMenu

Comment: Esta agregado al JTable

Comment: Podre la imagen de todo el programa

Comment: Listo amigo ya agregue las fotos

Comment: En la JTable, Solo tengo que darle click derecho a la persona que deseo eliminar, La cual la informacion que tiene se la proporciona al JButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega el indice, dado que son las mismas posiciones, también eliminará el otro del panel

```
private void eliminarInsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        int filasel;
        String id;
        try 
        {
            filasel = tblInstaladores.getSelectedRow();
            if(filasel == -1)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha seleccionado ninguna fila a eliminar");
            }
            else
            {
            modeloIns = (DefaultTableModel) tblInstaladores.getModel();    
            id = (String) modeloIns.getValueAt(filasel, 0);
            EliminarIns(id);
            }
            pnlIns.remove(filasel); //AQUÍ LO ELIMINAS
            pnlIns.revalidate();
            pnlIns.repaint();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

el problema sería si tus tables tienen sort, en ese caso, tendrías que tener más control al momento de hacer las llamadas a la BD, para que quede agrupado todo en una lista y no en llamadas locales.

EDITO: JPanel extiende de Component que tiene el metodo `remove(int index)`,si vez tu pnlIns como un arreglo, {persona1, persona2} y le dices `pnlIns.remove(0)`, quitará el de la posición 0 que es persona1.

También aclarar que Component también contiene un `remove(Component component)` donde elimina el objeto que le pases, por ejemplo `pnlIns.remove(persona2)` eliminara al objeto, aunque en tu caso es difícil aplicarlo dado que todos tus objetos son locales, es díficil obtener el objeto como tal, pero es importante que sepas que  se puede de las dos forma

Más información acerca del método remove con Index
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove(int)

Del remove con component
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove(java.awt.Component)

Comment: Wow hermano, GRACIAS!, Me solucionaste totalmente el problema, Oye, Sera que me puedes mandar algun articulo en el cual se explique lo que hiciste?

Comment: He editado la respuesta explicando un poco lo que se hizo y documentación de dicho método

Comment: Eres lo mejor! Gracias bro.